# Seeking Guidance on getting started with Machine Learning

Tags: deep-learning, automation

I have been active in development for many years, but commercially I have never had an opportunity to build something like https://www.ros-bot.com/ .   I want to find ways I can do something like that from home that interfaces with a program and be able to train it much like a "bot" to do things much quicker than I as a input user could provide.  Maybe this all falls under the category of deep learning.

So I am reaching out to this community for research idea, books, and or open source projects to tag along on, to find ways of automating and improving QoL of routine actions.   I am not looking to be nefarious and just trying to learn to one up my automated infrastructure that is beginning to grow at my house in both leisure and practical activities.

Answer (score 0):

First you should start form learning bout Supervised learning and unsupervised learning. There are some library that will helpful for you
Numpy, Pandas, Sklearn, Matplotlib, .You can watch videos on YouTube of Codebasics channel.